# My web docker container image not running

Tags: docker, laravel-5, docker-compose

I try to use docker  for laravel project and  I am using **Ubuntu** as a base image and laravel depedency but after docker-compose up only mysql and adminer container are running. My Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file are below

**My Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
Run apt-get update
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y apache2 
RUN apt-get install -y php7.0 php7.0-mysql php7.0-mbstring
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN  apt-get update
RUN  apt-get install -y git zip unzip
RUN  apt-get update
COPY laravel/ /var/www/html/
COPY laravel//vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
&& a2enmod rewrite
```

****docker yml file****

```
version: '2'

services:

db:
 image: mysql
 environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql
ports:
   - 8086:3306

adminer:
 image: adminer
 ports:
  - 8085:8080

web:
 image: laravel
ports:
  - 8889:80
volumes:
  - .bilbayt_admin/:/var/www/html/
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? "docker logs img"

Comment: No I am not getting any error.

Comment: For starters on the apache docker you need an entry point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now My Docker file look like this and it working**

FROM ubuntu:16.04 Run apt-get update RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install
-y apache2  RUN apt-get install -y php7.0 php7.0-mysql php7.0-mbstring
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php --
--install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN  apt-get update
RUN  apt-get install -y git zip unzip
RUN  apt-get update
COPY . /var/www/html
COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && a2enmod rewrite
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your Dockerfile, you need either an [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) or [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd), usually added as the last lines of your Dockerfile. These entries tell the image which command to run when you `docker run` (which is done in a roundabout way with `docker-compose up`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a cmd to start apache/an entry point.

Something like below at the end.

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```